# JavaScript returning array length of 0, but correct length in console

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-8

I have an HTML page with this block below. I cannot change it.
In JavaScript, I want to find all these `a` elements of class `language-link` and get their `hreflang` attribute, so I did this

```
var lang_links = document.getElementsByClassName('language-link');
for (var i = 0; i < lang_links.length; i++) {
    console.log(lang_links[i].getAttribute('hreflang'));
}
```

But for some reason, this doesn't print anything. I found out that `lang_links.length` is equal to 0. If I add the two `console.log` before the for loop like so,

```js
var lang_links = document.getElementsByClassName('language-link');

console.log(lang_links);
console.log("length: " + lang_links.length);

for (var i = 0; i < lang_links.length; i++) {
    console.log(lang_links[i].getAttribute('hreflang'));
}
```

```html
<nav class="links nav links-inline">
  <span hreflang="en" class="en nav-link is-active">
    <a href="/drupal/en" class="language-link is-active" hreflang="en">English</a>
  </span>
  <span hreflang="fr" class="fr nav-link">
    <a href="/drupal/fr" class="language-link" hreflang="fr">French</a>
  </span>
  <span hreflang="ar" class="ar nav-link">
    <a href="/drupal/ar" class="language-link" hreflang="ar">Arabic</a>
  </span>
</nav>
```

my browser's console prints

```
HTMLCollection []
> 0: a.language-link.is-active
> 1: a.language-link
> 2: a.language-link
  length: 3
> __proto__: HTMLCollection

length: 0
```

How does the array get printed correctly, even telling me the correct length, but when I print the array's length it says 0?

Also, if I run my code in the browser's console, I get the expected output that shows all `hreflang` attributes:

```
HTMLCollection(3) [a.language-link.is-active, a.language-link, a.language-link]
> 0: a.language-link.is-active
> 1: a.language-link
> 2: a.language-link
  length: 3
> __proto__: HTMLCollection

length: 3

en
fr
ar
```

Is it possibly due to the JavaScript code running before the elements get created? But if that was the case, `console.log(lang_links)` shouldn't have printed anything...

Edit: I am using Drupal 8, so I cannot change the script position in the HTML document (I think). I can't see my JavaScript files if I use the inspector, but it looks like Drupal runs scripts at the end of the body since this is where all scripts in the inspector appear and my others `getElementByClassName()` run with no problems.

Comment: Did you load JS somewhere on the header, before document loaded?

Comment: lang_links is an object and console shows the modified output for objects. You can verify this by adding a debugger statement after the console.log(lang_links). It would print undefined on console when debugger pauses the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the case, your JS code runs before the DOM loaded (or dynamically constructed if it is the case), because code itself works fine with static content.

Check the place where you are loading your script. If it is in the head or at the start of the body, move it bottom. As double benefit, it slightly increases page performance.

Regarding the second question, why it is shown on the console, @vcode already answered. DOM elements are objects and you see the "final result" of them.

Comment: I can't see my files if I use the inspector, but it looks like Drupal runs scripts at the end of the body since this is where all scripts in the inspector appear and my others calls to getElementByClassName() run with no problems.

Comment: Are you using some framework/code to create nodes dynamically? Open please your rendered HTML and check where ```<script></script>``` with your code placed?

Comment: Yes, I am using Drupal. The script tags are placed at the end of the body.

Comment: I am not familiar with Drupal, however, if it renders some markup dynamically in the runtime, this might be the reason. I would advise to test it with simple code ```setTimeout(() => {   if (!!document.querySelector('.language-link')) { console.log('I was created dynamically') } else {console.log('you missed')}}, 10000)``` And do a quick search in the codebase for the using ```language-link``` class. Might be you find how it is adding

Comment: Turns out they are created dynamically. Why does it work fine with everything else though? Anyway, thanks a lot!